# R - SQL aggregate min and max

Tags: sql, r, max, aggregate, min

Currently, I want to output dataframe from `iris` data set that will cover following query:

`SELECT MIN(Sepal.Width), MAX(Sepal.Width), Sepal.Length, species FROM iris GROUP BY Sepal.Length, species`

I create that code:

`query<-as.data.frame(aggregate(. ~ Sepal.Length, species, data = iris, FUN = function(x) c(min = min(x), maxi = max(x) ) ))`

But it does not output my expected result. I did that in sqldf and dplyr, but my question is:

How to do this with only `R-Base` functions?

Answer (score 2):

You're very close. Your problem is that `aggregate` uses the formula interface *instead* of `by`, not the two in conjunction. If you want to mimic `GROUP BY` from sql with multiple groups, put them on the right side of your formula.

```
query<-as.data.frame(aggregate(. ~ Species+Sepal.Length, 
                           data = iris, 
                           FUN = function(x) c(min = min(x), maxi = max(x) ) ))
```

If you're only interested in one trait, substitute it for the `.` on the left side of your formula.

```
query<-as.data.frame(aggregate(Sepal.Width ~ Species+Sepal.Length, 
                           data = iris, 
                           FUN = function(x) c(min = min(x), maxi = max(x) ) ))
```

Comment: Thank you, but this solution gives 3 variables and do not output min and max values of "Sepal.Width" variable. 
My struggle is - how to output min and max from Sepal.Width for each group?

Comment: @Klaus012 I'm not sure I understand your question. If you just want max and min of Sepal.Width by species, just use Sepal.Width~Species as your formula

Comment: Exactly, I did like that, also changed in function from `min = min(x)` to `mini = min(x)`, but there are only 3 variables, instead 4 (4 = min(sepal.width), max(sepal.width), species and sepal.length)

Comment: If you want Sepal.Width aggregated by species and Sepal.Length, just include them all in your formula, e.g. `Sepal.Width ~ Species+Sepal.Length`. You can think of the formula here as [things I want to apply the function to] ~ [variables I want them aggregated by]

Comment: Yes this I understand, of course, but I struggle with function. Like it does not work (it does not output min AND max in two separate columns) and I dont know why, because it compiles and should work fine.

Comment: Can you edit your post to show exactly what function you are running and exactly what the output is? If I run `as.data.frame(aggregate(Sepal.Width ~ Species+Sepal.Length,data = iris,FUN = function(x) c(mini = min(x), maxi = max(x) ) ))` I get 4 columns: Species, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width.mini, Sepal.Width.maxi

Comment: I run the same command assign to query, and have 3 columns:

Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width

Like this command doesnt see function(x)